# XSLT enumerate each child element

Tags: css, xml, xslt, styles

I am trying to create a super generic XSLT that basically can only count on the table & row elements being there. I have the following sample XML I am trying to make an XSLT for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
    <row>
        <id>5311</id>
        <status>Active</status>
        <id_vendor>Verizon</id_vendor>
        <mobile_number>555123456</mobile_number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>5312</id>
        <status>Inactive</status>
        <id_vendor>Sprint</id_vendor>
        <mobile_number>555123457</mobile_number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>5313</id>
        <status>Active</status>
        <id_vendor>ATT</id_vendor>
        <mobile_number>555123458</mobile_number>
    </row>
</table>
```

The problem is that I do not know what the fields are going to end up being (id, status, id_vendor, mobile_number, etc. are all subject to change.

I want to make pleasant to look at view such as:

```
<div style="background-color:#E3CA87;padding:.2em">
    <div style="background-color:#F1E2BB;padding:.2em">
        <div>id: x<div>
        <div>status: active<div>
        <div>id_vendor: Verizon<div>
        <div>mobile_number: 555123456<div>
    <div>
<div>
```

Here is what I have so far.. but I can't get the anonymous elements going right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="background-color:#eee;font-size:12pt;font-family:Arial;">
    <xsl:for-each select="table/row">
      <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:.5em">

       <xsl:for-each select="/*">

       <div style="background-color:#E3CA87;padding:.2em;border: 1px solid black">
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
          <div style="background-color:#F1E2BB;padding:.2em">
<xsl:value-of select ="name(./*)"/>: 
<xsl:value-of select="*" />
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After your edit you would need to drop the `<xsl:for-each select="/*">`, you could then shorten `<xsl:for-each select="./*">` to `<xsl:for-each select=".*">` and then you need use `<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close... but it was actually a little differnt.. just figured it out for anyone that want's to know:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="background-color:#eee;font-size:12pt;font-family:Arial;">
    <xsl:for-each select="table/row">
      <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:.5em">

       <xsl:for-each select=".">

       <div style="background-color:#E3CA87;padding:.2em;border: 1px solid black">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
<xsl:for-each select="./*">
          <div style="background-color:#F1E2BB;padding:.2em">
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(.), ': ', .)" />
          </div>        
</xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Throw out the `for-each select="."`, it does nothing but litter the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="*">` instead of `<xsl:for-each select="/*">`. Then I think you want to drop the inner for-each and simply replace it with

```
<div style="background-color:#F1E2BB;padding:.2em">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ': ', .)" />
          </div>
```